# How to sign my already made android app/.apk file

Tags: android, certificate, apk, sign

I have made an Android Live wallpaper application using a software and the app is running perfectly on my device so I thought about uploading it to Playstore.When I uploaded my app it game me following error :

**

"You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon.
You need to sign your APK with a certificate that expires farther into the future."

Now how I can sign my certificate again ? 
Please I need detailed tutorial !

Comment: Did you create your app using Eclipse? How did you create it and how did you generate the APK file?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a new signing key that will expire in 25 years or so and sign your application toth that key

Answer (score 0):

to generate map key:=

go to  C:\users....android.
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\users....android\debug.keystore 
-storepass android -keypass android
MD5 finger print:
79:9F:B9:2B:F0:51:C8:48:2E:39:5B:72:AB:42:24:91
map key:
0lujtKtuh8x_MfEUSN5OpCj6HVCxX9lvBDgCT2w

---

to generate certificate:=

keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA 
-keysize 2048 -validity 10000
password1- ...,123

### password2- ....,1234

previous map key generated : 0Vd9Hpw3AaaLfuaYgC8btoNu8OkuZe4bPXD9oPg

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Create a release.keystore (it not already done):
  `keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
- Remove the old signature:
  `zip -d foo.apk META-INF/\*`
- Sign with the new key:
  `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore release.keystore my_application.apk alias_name`
- Verify the signature:

  `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk`